# PHP odbc_fetch_array fail when query has a join with same fieldname SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I've found an issue while working with php ODBC functions.
odbc_fetch_array and odbc_fetch_object fail when query has a join with a table that has the same column name, even when that certain field is excluded from the field selection:

for example

```
$con = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=$serverName;Database=$db;", 'user', 'pass',SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);

$query="SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2 from table1 JOIN table2 ON  table1.field1=table2.field1";

$result = odbc_exec($con,$query);

 $a=odbc_fetch_array($result);
```

the code above generates a warning:

> Warning:  odbc_fetch_array() [function.odbc-fetch-array]: SQL error:
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]the column name
>   '' is ambiguous., SQL state 37000 in SQLGetData

The error would be okay if i had selected field1 without specifying from which table, but even when it is explicit it doesn't work. the only "workaround" i've found so far is to remove the field from the selected fields or changinf the field name from the second table

I tried with:
both SQL Server Native Client 10.0 and SQL Server Native Client 11.0
SQL server 2008
Php 5.3.2
over Windows

PD: If someone has any aideas without using sqlsrv or mssqL extension it will be great

Comment: Have you tried back-ticking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found out the issue was caused due to a column with "text" type on SQL server database, odbc_fetch_array fails when the query has one or more joins to tables that have the same column name and in the selected fields you include a text type column.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a typo while writing the post cause this looks weird `table1.field1=table2=field1`. It should be `table1.field1 = table2.field1`

```
SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2 from table1 JOIN table2 
ON  table1.field1=table2=field1
                         <--Here
```

Comment: You're right i had a typo error on the query, but on the real ones there's no typo error but still having the issue. it fails when i have same column names in joined tables